# why isn't this being found with the specified regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am using this regex in python:

```
=\s*[^(]([Tt]rue|[Ff]alse)
```

When I execute it, it is matching the items shown. However I also expect it to match the 7th item, because the beginning of the regex says an '=' followed by 0 or more white space characters (i.e spaces, tabs etc) and on line 7 there are 0 whites space characters. So why isn't it matching?

```
1 password = True (matched)
2 password = true (matched)
3 password = false (matched)
4 password = False (matched)
5 password "False"
6 password = 'True' (matched)
7 password =False (not matched but expected to be)
8 password =dict(required=False, default=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is an equal sign `=`, followed by zero or more whitespace `\s*`, **followed by any character other than '('** `[^(]`, followed by the word true or false `([Tt]rue|[Ff]alse)`

In item 7, the "any character other than (" pattern is matched by the letter F. After than is "alse" which isn't the word true and isn't the word false.

Answer (score 1):

`[^(]` means you require a character that isn't `(` between the (possibly empty) sequence of spaces and the word `True` or `False`. There's no such character on that line.

You can make that character optional.

```
^[^(\n]*=\s*[^(]?([Tt]rue|[Ff]alse)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/1WH7NQ/3)

Comment: yes but now it matches  #8 too and i don't want that

Comment: Is `(required=False, default=None)` really part of the input? I thought that was just your comments saying whether the string before it should be matched.

Comment: If it is part of the real input, why shouldn't it match? You want to match `=True` or `=False`, and `required=False` contains that.

Comment: If you only want to match `password = True` or `pasword = False`, add `password` to the beginning of the regexp.

Comment: yes it is part of the real input , sorry should have clarified that.  we do not want #8 matched because we just want to get  = followed by immediately by 0 or more white spaces and then  a true or false

Comment: Then why shouldn't it match? `required=False` contains `=` followed by zero spaces followed by `False`.

Comment: Do you only want to match starting from the first `=` on the line, so this should fail because it contains `=dict` before it?

Comment: it should not match required=False  because I specify in the regex that i do not want any true false inside parentheses.  I only want = and 0 or more white space only and then true or false ....

Comment: Your regexp say you don't want a parenthesis between `=` and `true/false`. It doesn't say anything about parentheses around the whole thing, or anything else outside of the `=true/false`

Comment: true the regex is not checking for the closing parentheses,  that is fine. just need to match = with any number of white space  or no space then true or false( [Tt]rue|[Ff]alse )  .  and i don't get why the * after \s is not recognizing when it is 0 white space.

Comment: It is recognizing when it is 0 white space. Then it matches `[^(]`, which consumes the next character, which is `F`. Then it tries to match `False` or `True`, but at that point it's just `alse`.

Comment: That's why I make the `[^(]` optional. This allows it to backtrack and ignore that pattern, and match `False`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the closing parentheses. The problem is that you have no restrictions on what comes before `=False`. There's nothing that says that you can't have `(blah blah =False)`. You only prohibit `(` after `=`, not before it.

Comment: I've updated the regexp to add `^[^(]*` before `=`. It no longer matches 8.

Comment: I changed it to `^[^(\n]` so it won't match across multiple lines.

Comment: so are you saying matching across lines is an issue?

Comment: It was an issue in my regex101.com demo, and it could be in your application if you process multi-line input.

Comment: It was matching the combination of lines 5 and 6.

Comment: yes I do process multi line input.  Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

```
[^(]
```

ahh after edit its correct. that means one any not - `[^'(']` symbol after =\s* and THEN [Ff]alse, so it would batch only if some symbol is between = and [Ff]alse